# Threejs - dinamically adjust camera distance to set 3d object equal to desired pixel

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm still new to three.js and I've been trying to find out if there's a way to calculate and adjust camera distance so that the object inside threejs canvas can be set into exact pixels I want. For example, I want 300 pixels width so that when I print screen the browser the object rendered in threejs should be 300px accurate if you measure the printscreen image.

The reason why I want to do this is because I want to render an actual size 3D credit card model in Three.js.

[image]

Comment: You can scale the object to the right amount to get the size fit the screen.

Comment: I need to calculate it dynamically because it will have different sizes. Not just credit card object

Comment: You might be able (though I doubt it would be easy, as you have to cater for different aspect ratios) to get your object to display at say 300px with three.js, it would be much easier using a simpler system like canvas. But even then you don't know the monitor's PPI, and you don't know the current browser's scaling. All in all you just won't be able to tell how large it is as it is displayed on screen.